# Similar code in Tasks returning different status codes

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I am throwing an `OperationCanceledException` from three different Tasks and each having slight differences, as per the code below:

```
static async Task ThrowCancellationException()
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t1 = new Task(() => throw new OperationCanceledException());
    t1.Start();
    try { t1.Wait(); } catch { }

    Task t2 = new Task(async () => throw new OperationCanceledException());
    t2.Start();
    try { t2.Wait(); } catch { }

    Task t3 = ThrowCancellationException();

    Console.WriteLine(t1.Status); // prints Faulted
    Console.WriteLine(t2.Status); // prints RanToCompletion
    Console.WriteLine(t3.Status); // prints Canceled
}
```

My question is:

***Why the statuses are different for each task?***

I could understand that there are differences between the code/lambdas marked with `async` and the lambda not marked with `async` but the status is different even between the `async` lambda and the `async` method running the same code.

Comment: "*but the status is different even between the async lambda and the async method running the same code*" -- not true. That overload of `new Task` takes an `Action`, not a `Func<Task>`, meaning your `async` lambda version is equivalent to passing an `async void` method, not an `async Task` method. Use `Task.Run` if you want to pass in a delegate which returns a `Task`: it's got an overload which takes a `Func<Task>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could understand that there are differences between the code/lambdas marked with async and the lambda not marked with async but the status is different even between the async lambda and the async method running the same code.

This isn't quite true.

If you look carefully at that `new Task(async () => throw new OperationCanceledException())`, you'll see it's calling the overload `new Task(Action action)` (there's no overload which takes a `Func<Task>`). This means that it's equivalent to passing an `async void` method, not an `async Task` method.

---

So:

```
Task t2 = new Task(async () => throw new OperationCanceledException());
t2.Start();
try { t2.Wait(); } catch { }
```

This compiles to something like:

```
private static async void CompilerGeneratedMethod()
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException()
}
...
Task t2 = new Task(CompilerGeneratedMethod);
t2.Start();
try { t2.Wait(); } catch { }
```

This grabs a thread from the ThreadPool, and runs `CompilerGeneratedMethod` on it. When an exception is throw from inside an `async void` method, the exception is re-thrown somewhere appropriate (in this case, it's re-thrown on the ThreadPool), but the `CompilerGeneratedMethod` method itself returns straight away. This causes the `Task t2` to complete straight away, which is why its status is `RanToCompletion`.

So what happened to the exception? It's about to bring down your application! Stick a `Console.ReadLine` at the end of your `Main`, and see that the application exits before you have a chance to press enter.

---

This:

```
Task t3 = ThrowCancellationException();
```

is very different. It's not attempting to run anything on the ThreadPool. `ThrowCancellationException` is run synchronously, and synchronously returns a `Task` which contains the `OperationCanceledException`. A `Task` which contains an `OperationCanceledException` is treated as `Canceled`.

---

If you want to run an `async` method on the ThreadPool, use `Task.Run`. This has an overload which takes a `Func<Task>`, which means that:

```
Task t2 = Task.Run(async () => throw new OperationCanceledException());
```

Compiles to something like:

```
private static async Task CompilerGeneratedMethod()
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
}
...
Task t2 = Task.Run(CompilerGeneratedMethod);
```

Here, when `CompilerGeneratedMethod` is executed on the ThreadPool, it returns a `Task` containing the `OperationCanceledException`. The Task machinery then transitions the `Task t2` to the `Canceled` state.

---

As an aside, avoid `new Task`, and prefer using `Task.Run` if you want to explicitly run a method on the ThreadPool. There are lots of methods in the TPL which were introduced before async/await, and are confusing when used with it.

Comment: okay so between the async lambda and the async method, the return type would be different. Didn't knew that. Also *Stick a Console.ReadLine at the end of your Main, and see that the application exits before you have a chance to press enter.* - Indeed, I was checking it with a breakpoint at the end and did not noticed the exception. Great answer!

Comment: @meJustAndrew That's the relevant bit, but there's another difference between `t2` and `t3`: `t2` uses `new Task(...).Start()`,which runs the given method on the ThreadPool. `t3` just calls `ThrowCancellationException` directly, and the ThreadPool isn't involved.

Comment: I see, thanks for making this clear this way, I was confused about when is the thread pool involved and not. So if I would have called the constructor of the Task and given the method as a parameter, then it would go on thread pool as I call start, but a direct call is going to run it on the current thread until it reaches an `await` id I understand correctly.

Comment: @meJustAndrew That's correct. Substituting `new Task` for `Task.Run` makes it a bit clearer: it's running the given method on the ThreadPool. `new Task` was introduced before `async/await` was a thing, and it wasn't clear that `Task` would end up representing "a bit of asynchronous work that might not have completed yet", rather than "code running synchronously on another thread which might not have completed yet". If `Task` were introduced today, I doubt it would have a `Start` method.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a task using the `Task` constructor, you can provide a `CancellationToken` as optional argument. The task will result in a `Canceled` state only in case of an `OperationCanceledException` that is associated with this specific `CancellationToken`. Otherwise the exception will be interpreted as a fault. Here is how you can associate an `OperationCanceledException` with a `CancellationToken`:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t1 = new Task(() =>
{
    cts.Cancel();
    throw new OperationCanceledException(cts.Token);
}, cts.Token);
```

About using the `Task` constructor with an async delegate as argument, the correct way to do it is by creating a nested `Task<Task>`:

```
Task<Task> t2 = new Task<Task>(async () => throw new OperationCanceledException());
t2.Start();
try { t2.Result.Wait(); } catch { }

Console.WriteLine(t2.Result.Status); // prints Canceled
```

Comment: Note that [`Task.Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap?view=netframework-4.8) is a thing, which can help in those (rare) situations you have a `Task<Task>`

Comment: @canton7 yeap, you can call `Unwrap` to the nested task after you start it. But you do need the initial reference to the nested task so that you can call its `Start` method. If you try to `Start` the unwrapped task directly you'll get an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a promise-style task.`